# Escape command parameters for re-use in Bash?

Tags: bash, escaping

I want to save command parameters for re-use in a variable in Bash. The reason is they are very long and I use them multiple times.

```
SRC_FOLDER="src folder"
DST_FOLDER="dst folder"
PARAMS="--dry-run \"$SRC_FOLDER\" \"$DST_FOLDER\""
rsync $PARAMS
```

The problem is the space in the src and dst folder. Rsync thinks there are 4 folders instead of 2. I think I somehow have to escape the variables in line 3.

I cannot escape the folders in line 1 and 2 because they might have been passed to my bash script by parameter and I don't know the content.

Please also note that the src and dst folders may have other special signs like *, $, \, ", '.

Is this possible without using separate variables like this:

```
rsync $PARAMS "$SRC_FOLDER" "$DST_FOLDER"
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: You can use an array for that. You may have an additional problem though: is the destination remote?

Comment: Can you please post an answer using an array? What do you mean by remote? If you mean the rsync destination than it doesn't play a role because rsync is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

rsync_args=(
    --dry-run
    "src folder"
    "dst folder"
)

rsync "${rsync_args[@]}"
```

---

###### About the problem that I mentioned in my comment:

The remote path in `rsync` commands is subject to word splitting.

The following example is wrong:

```sh
rsync -av ~/ user@server:'home backup 2021-12-04/'
```

You have to write it like this:

```sh
rsync -av ~/ user@server:'home\ backup\ 2021-12-04/'
```

A way for fixing it automatically is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
remote_path='home backup 2021-12-04/'
qq="'\''"
rsync -av ~/ user@server:"'${remote_path//\'/$qq}'"
```

Comment: I don't have a remote destination so I simply used an array as shown in your example. It is working fine.